# Is there a way to to set a socket option to indicate which interface the packets go to

Tags: c, unix, network-programming

Currently, this is my predicament. 
I have 2 fd's : x and y. When a write(x) happens, it must go to x-tunnel and a write(y) should go to y-tunnel. I cannot create a routing rule for each connection (Reasons not mentioned here)

Is there a sock opt which I can set when I accept a connection or is there any other way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried binding the sockets to the interface connected to the route which you want to use?

Comment: The interface is virtual, it is not possible to bind since a single connection can have writes to x and y interface

Comment: In practice this means the user (sysadmin) needs a way to specify what IP address ends up being sent to `bind`.  The admin must then somehow specify the right address for the interface she wants to use.  And in you particular case she needs to be able to do this once for X and once for Y.

Comment: A physical interface has 2 virtual interfaces. Binding it will send it to eventually out from physical. But classification needs to be done on the virtual.. I don't think this can be done by binding.

Comment: And those two virtual interfaces should have different IP addresses, so you can bind to those addresses.

Comment: No. They both have 0.0.0.0..BINDING is not possible. The classification should be done when actually doing write on fd. This is the problem statement. Looking for a solution for this..if there is one!

Comment: Assuming Linux, perhaps you want to use `SO_BINDTODEVICE`?

Comment: You can not send/route IP-packages via an interface without IP-address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you can control in sock binding on specific interface for x, y tunnels
- check for SO_DONTROUTE option in setsockopt

Answer (score -1):

Your description is sketchy, I think setsockopt()  by optname  of SO_REUSEADDR and SO_REUSEPORT may help you, but I'm not sure.It can't 'indicate' which interface the packets go to,but you can indicate them by your implement.

Here some reference on Unix Network Programming, if you want to know more detail,you can read them and examples in chapter7.5.

> The SO_REUSEADDR socket option serves four different purposes:
>
> 1. SO_REUSEADDR allows a listening server to start and bind its well-known port, 
>      even if previously established connections exist that use this port as their local 
>      port.
> 2. SO_REUSEADDR allows a new server to be started on the same port as an 
>      existing server that is bound to the wildcard address, as long as each instance 
>      binds a different local IP address.
> 3. **SO_REUSEADDR allows a single process to bind the same port to multiple 
>      sockets, as long as each bind specifies a different local IP address.**
> 4. SO_REUSEADDR allows completely duplicate bindings: a bind of an IP address 
>      and port, when that same IP address and port are already bound to another 
>      socket, if the transport protocol supports it. Normally this feature is supported
>      only for UDP sockets.